# Breeze.js cache limitations? Or Browser?

Tags: javascript, orm, breeze

We are investigating using Breeze for field deployment of some tools.  The scenario is this -- an auditor will visit sites in the field, where most of the time there will be no -- or very degraded -- internet access. Rather than replicate our SQL database on all the laptops and tablets (if that's even possible), we are hoping to use Breeze to cache the data and then store it locally so it is accessible when there is not a usable connection.

Unfortunately, Breeze seems to choke when caching any significant amount of data.  Generally on Chrome it's somewhere between 8 and 13MB worth of entities (as measured by the HTTPResponse headers).  This can change a bit depending on how many tabs I have open and such, but I have not been able to move that more than 10%.  the error I get is the Chrome tab crashes and tells me to reload.  The error is replicable (I download the data in 100K chunks and it fails on the same read every time and works fine if I stop it after the previous read) When I change the page size, it always fails within the same range.

Is this a limitation of Breeze, or Chrome? Or windows?  I tried it on Firefox, and it handles even less data before the whole browser crashes.  IE fares a little better, but none of them do great.

Looking at performance in task manager, I get the following:

1. IE goes from 250M memory usage to 1.7G of memory usage during the caching process and caches a total of about 14MB before throwing an out-of-memory error.
2. Chrome goes from 206B memory usage to about 850M while caching a total of around 9MB
3. Firefox goes from around 400M to about 750M and manages to cache about 5MB before the whole program crashes.

I can calculate how much will be downloaded with any selection criteria, but I cannot find a way to calculate how much data can be handled by any specific browser instance.  This makes using Breeze for offline auditing close to useless.

Has anyone else tackled this problem yet?  What are the best approaches to handling something like this.  I've thought of several things, but none of them are ideal.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

ADDED At Steve Schmitt's request:

Here are some helpful links:

- [Metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6upbnfqjrjp3vv/RST_CHMetadata.txt?dl=0)
- [Entity Diagram (pdf)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o43xts427uiuqf8/RST_CHContext.pdf?dl=0) (and [html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2wijiacsxd0rsz/RST_CHContext.html?dl=0) and [edmx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gla1w7s4zkp517j/RST_ClientHistoryContext.edmx?dl=0))

The first query, just to populate the  tags on the page runs quickly and downloads minimal data:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from("Countries")
                .orderBy("Name")
                .expand("Regions.Districts.Seasons, Regions.Districts.Sites");
```

Once the user has select the Sites s/he wishes to cache, the following two queries are kicked off (used to be one query, but I broke it into two hoping it would be less of a burden on resources -- it didn't help).  The first query (usually 2-3K entities and about 2MB) runs as expected.  Some combination of the predicates listed are used to filter the data.

```
var qry = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from("SeasonClients")
                    .expand("Client,Group.Site,Season,VSeasonClientCredit")
                    .orderBy("DistrictId,SeasonId,GroupId,ClientId")

    var p = breeze.Predicate("District.Region.CountryId", "==", CountryId);
    var p1 = breeze.Predicate("SeasonId", "==", SeasonId);
    var p2 = breeze.Predicate("DistrictId", "==", DistrictId);
    var p3 = breeze.Predicate("Group.Site.SiteId", "in", SiteIds);
```

After the first query runs, the second query (below) runs (also using some combination of the predicates listed to filter the data. At about 9MB, it will have about 50K rows to download).  When the total download burden between the two queries is between 10MB and 13MB, browsers will crash.

```
var qry = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from("Repayments")
                    .orderBy('SeasonId,ClientId,RepaymentDate');

    var p1 = breeze.Predicate("District.Region.CountryId", "==", CountryId);
    var p2 = breeze.Predicate("SeasonId", "==", SeasonId);
    var p3 = breeze.Predicate("DistrictId", "==", DistrictId);
    var p4 = breeze.Predicate("SiteId", "in", SiteIds);
```

Thanks for the interest, Steve.  You should know that the Entity Relationships are inherited and currently in production supporting the majority of the organization's operations, so as few changes as possible to that would be best.  Also, the hope is to grow this from a reporting application to one with which data entry can be done in the field (so, as I understand it, using projections to limit the data wouldn't work).

Thanks for the interest, and let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: Can you give some more information about your data?  Maybe provide the metadata for the entities that you are caching?  It might help determine if there's a bug somewhere that is causing the problem.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the interest.  Updated the question to give a bit more information.

Comment: In your tests what are you doing with the query results? Throwing them away? Storing them? Clearing cache with `manager.clear()` between requests? Trying to understand what phase causes trouble. I do believe each browser has its own choke point for payload size but I doubt that's it. I'm leaning toward "too many entities in memory" in which case we need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Ward, good questions.  Right now, I'm doing nothing with the data between requests.  I'm just trying to get the data into the cache.  When I need the data I'll load handle that with queryLocally.  An interesting fact: if I read 4 MB of data, the browser memory usage increases by about 600 MB (tripling, or in the case of IE, quadrupling and using an additional 1+ gig of memory).  Yet, if I export the entities to save them in local storage, the entire JSON string is about 4 GB.  So something happening in in the actual downloading/processing is hogging system memory. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: ...entire JSON string is about 4MB..." not GB.  Sorry, too late to edit.  To emphasize: the export is acting exactly as expected (exporting about the same amount of data as downloaded), but something is eating system memory during the download.  THanks.

Comment: We are trying to repro your issue but so far no luck. We are trying to come up with a simple test ( and model) that repros your problem. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Great Jay.  What can I do to help.  I could send you my data and and EF schema, but my internet connection is pretty crappy here in East Africa.  Some additional information: I simplified the schema somewhat and was able to squeeze an extra 10% out of the browser, but that doesn't seem significant.  I'll try to trim some more tomorrow -- maybe I'll find the relationship causing the problem.  I used the noTracking option on the bigger part of the download and it, of course, showed no bump in browser memory usage no matter how big.  Anything you'd like me to try or provide? I'm v. willing.

Comment: I can send you what I am able to export.  If you import it it won't make the browser crash, but you might see the memory spike.  I could also send you 20+ MB of pojos with the metadata maybe converting them to entities will create the problem.  Just let me know.

Comment: @Jay, I don't know if you got my last comment since I didn't tag you. I'd be glad to help you recreate this issue.  I'm using Jeremy Danyow's suggestions, but finding that I'm having to code fairly differently when on-line versus off-line (For example, search by name or phone number) which is a bit of a maintenance burden that I was hoping Breeze could mitigate a bit more.  If I could regularly double the amount of data that I can currently load, that would take care of most of my problems.  Thanks.

Comment: @Beartums, we are still trying to repro your issue. We do see a significant memory bump during large queries, which is somewhat expected, but in our tests this memory appears to be reclaimed after the query completes.  Which means that you might be able to mitigate the issue by breaking the query up into pieces via take and skip.

Comment: @Jay, that's what I figured, too.  But I'm using .take(100) and .skip(100*pagesRead) for all my queries, and it doesn't make a difference.  I also tried querying some of the entities separately, but the memory usage keeps climbing and stays elevated until I explicitly clear the cache.  I'll keep trying from my side.  Let me know if I can help.  I appreciate you're getting back to me.  Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the in-memory size, a lot of extra memory is used when wrapping the entity properties in Knockout observables.  Using the Knockout model library takes 3+ times the amount of memory that, say, AngularJS properties require.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the information.  That's good to know, though still surprising that 25MB of api data is eating up about 1GB of memory when being wrapped.  I'll see what we can do to work within these limits.

Comment: @Steve, Excellent get.  I just rewrote my app in Angular and am able to cache what appears to be an unlimited amount of data from the same EF6 model.  While the knockout version of the client app craps out at around 5MB (chrome memory peaking at about 1.7GB) unless I use the noTracking option, I have so far been able to cache over 50MB using Angular with chrome memory usage never going past about 625MB.  Valuable Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeremy's answer was excellent and very helpful, but didn't actually answer the question, which I was starting to think was unanswerable, or at least the wrong question.  However @Steve in the comments gave me the most appropriate information for this question.

It is neither Breeze nor the Browser, but rather Knockout.  Apparently the knockout wrapper around the breeze entities uses all that memory (at least while loading the entities and in my environment).  As described above, Knockout/Breeze would crap out after reading around 5MB of data, causing Chrome to crash with over 1.7GB of memory usage (from a pre-download memory usage around 300MB).  Rewriting the app in ANgularJS eliminated the problem.  So far I have been able to download over 50MB from the exact same EF6 model into Breeze/Angular, total Chrome memory usage never went above 625MB.

I will be testing larger payloads, but 50 MB more than satisfies my needs for the moment.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some **suggestions** based on my experience building on an offline capable web application using breeze.   Some or all of these might not make sense for your use cases...

1. Identify which entity types need to be editable vs which are used to fill drop-downs etc.  Load non-editable data using the [noTracking](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_noTracking) query option and cache them in localStorage yourself using JSON.stringify.  This avoids the overhead of coercing the data into entities, change tracking, etc.  Good candidates for this approach in your model might be entity types like Country, Region, District, Site, etc.
2. If possible, provide a facility in your application for users to identify which records they want to "take offline".  This way you don't need to load and cache everything, which can get quite expensive depending on the number of relationships, entities, properties, etc.
3. In conjunction with suggestion #2, avoid loading all the editable data at once and avoid using the same EntityManager instance to load each set of data.  For example, if the Client entity is something that needs to be editable out in the field without a connection, create a new EntityManager, load a single client (expanding any children that also need to be editable) and cache this data separately from other clients.
4. Cache the breeze metadata once.  When calling [exportEntities](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_exportEntities) the includeMetadata argument should be false.  More info on this [here](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/exportimport).
5. To create new EntityManager instances make use of the [createEmptyCopy](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_createEmptyCopy) method.

**EDIT:**

I want to respond to this comment:

> Say I have a client who has bills and payments. That client is in a
>   group, in a site, in a region, in a country. Are you saying that the
>   client, payment, and bill information might each have their own EM,
>   while the location hierarchy might be in a 4th EM with no-tracking?
>   Then when I refer to them, I wire up the relationships as needed using
>   LINQs on the different EMs (give me all the bills for customer A, give
>   me all the payments for customer A)?

It's a bit of a judgement call in terms of deciding how to separate things out.  Some of what I'm suggesting might be overkill, it really depends on the amount of data and the way your application is used.

Assuming you don't need to edit groups, sites, regions and countries while offline, the first thing I'd do would be to load the list of groups using the noTracking option and cache them in localStorage for offline use.  Then do the same for sites, regions and countries.  Keep in mind, entities loaded with the noTracking option aren't cached in the entity manager so you'll need to grab the query result, JSON.stringify it and then call localStorage.setItem.  The intent here is to make sure your application always has access to the list of groups, sites, regions, etc so that when you display a form to edit a client entity you'll have the data you need to populate the group, site, region and country select/combobox/dropdown.

Assuming the user has identified the subset of clients they want to work with while offline, I'd then load each of these clients one at a time (including their payment and bill information but not expanding their group, site, region, country) and cache each client+payments+bills set using entityManager.exportEntities.  Reasoning here is it doesn't make sense to load several clients plus their payments and bills into the same EntityManager each time you want to edit a particular client.  That could be a lot of unnecessary overhead, but again, this is a bit of a judgement call.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for your thoughts.  They look like some good ideas and I'll try them asap.  A few questions: 1) if I use notracking, does that disrupt the relationships and LINQ capabilities? 2} I have already introduced filters to get the total payload below a certain size, but right now that size is a moving target, 3) Same questions as #1.  I want to retain the relationships and the LINQ capabilites, but maybe I'm not understanding what separate entity managers will do, 4) I don't think this is an issue, as exporting is working beautifully.  I will look into all these options.

Comment: When using noTracking you still get the linq style query stuff (where, orderBy, expand, etc).  The difference is the results of the query are not converted to entities and tracked by the EntityManager, which keeps the client-side processing minimal.

For example, lets say your users need to create new Client entities while offline.  You don't need a District entity to create a new Client.  You could load the list of Districts using noTracking and use the DistrictId and Name to create a the "district" select element on the new Client form.

Comment: re: separate EntityManagers, this might not make sense in your case but for my project, it did not make sense to serialize/deserialize all of the entities to/from localStorage when making edits.  In my case I used one EntityManager per set of entities I wanted to edit-  unit of work style.  In my case users could select several consumers to work with offline.  Each consumer is cached separately along with their phones, addresses, etc.

Comment: I was thinking you might be hitting performance problems / memory pressure when loading a lot of entities into a single EntityManager due to all the processing breeze has to do to connect all the relationships, track the entities.  I don't think the EntityManager is intended to be used this way, I think it's more common for an entity manager to track a subset of entities that are being edited on a particular screen.

Comment: Thanks.  Based on what you're saying, I'm still not sure how this all fits together. Say I have a client who has bills and payments. That client is in a group, in a site, in a region, in a country. Are you saying that the client, payment, and bill information might each have their own EM, while the location hierarchy might be in a 4th EM with no-tracking? Then when I refer to them, I wire up the relationships as needed using LINQs on the different EMs (give me all the bills for customer A, give me all the payments for customer A)?

Comment: Then, if I add a payment, does the foreign key propagate properly?  This is probably too large a topic for me to glean the intricacies in these comments.  Do you know of anywhere I could find examples and deeper explanation of these concepts? Thanks.

Comment: Jeremy, I'm using your suggestions, which have been helpful, but I have a few questions (maybe I should start a new question). If I use POJO's, I have to write my own search routines (by name, phone number, etc.), right?  Unless, of course, I'm online, when I can use LINQ to query the database.  I'm a bit worried about that.  It seems like I would have to develop two lines -- one for online, one for offline.  Obv., I could always search the offline data the same way (even when online), but the benefit of being online is being able to query the entire set.  How do you handle this?

Comment: Depends on your design. In my case attempting to search while offline displays a message like this "Looks like you're offline... you can access consumers you've made available offline on the <a>Downloaded</a> tab".  My email is in my profile, send me a message if you want to see this in action.  Maybe what we're doing doesn't map to what you're doing as well as I'm thinking.

Comment: Can't find your email in your profile, but I'd love to pick your brain a bit.  If you're game, please drop me a line at yx0kq+7u6ad5ksqeifc@sharklasers.com so I have a way to contact you.  THanks!

Comment: Actually this one might be better: yxc88+ekdih7jnof3vo@sharklasers.com. Thanks.